# How to make better content display

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, shadowbox

We are developing a social networking project, in this project we are adding content, e.g. images, video, audio, link (html).

Currently we are using shadowbox.js to show it. But for better and effectiveness we want to use some other better plugin, or want to make own window for showing images and link.

What is the best solution for this project?

I want to know this is the white board question means programmer.stackexchange question or stackoverflow question?

Comment: you want to create your own lightbox plugin? basically you could write your own jQuery lightbox plugin, or you could use an exiting plugin and restyle it to you liking, i personally like colorbox, it is easy to restyle, or you could create basically a card, with css, and create the content on the fly with jQuery ex:  $('#link').click(function(){$('body').append("<div class="card"></div>")});  thats basically what you would be doing writign the plugin, but a plugin would be cleaner more reusable code.

Comment: your not going to be able to write a plugin without knowing javascript or jQuery fairly well, but if you just google it, you can find some tutorials, for your case i would suggest just using an exising plugin and restyling it, it will save you time and effort, like i said, colorbox works great with flash, ajax content, and iframes, images, it even has a built in option for image slideshows.

Comment: The last sentence in this question is fairly nonsensical, but the rest of it is far too broad, and the answer is not useful for anyone. I recommend this question is closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made my own div and use that for displaying content :)

Answer (score 1):

There are 31 here:

http://www.dreamcss.com/2009/03/31-mind-blowing-collection-of-jquery.html

You should find one or more that suits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using colorbox.js it can be found here :

http://colorpowered.com/

It is easily styled, comes with a pleathera of options including an image slideshow, can handle iFrames, Ajax content, Images, etc, and comes with a few options for styling to begin with.